# Apply event only to the pointed element but not its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseevent, children

I created a simple annotation feature using jquery. The annotation feature works fine i.e it does create a comment box when I click on the page. but it has a drawback that when I click even on the comment box, a new comment box get creates. This is not what I want.

I want to create a new comment box when the user clicks on the `.body` element but not its child elements i.e comment boxes.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/70b4Loh1/11/)

I tried to solve this by specifically mentioning the child elements as shown in the below code. but this doesn't even trigger the event on the `.body` element.

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.body', function (e) {
      //code here
}).on('mousedown', '.body *', function(e){ return false; });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can try is to check whether `e.target` is `.body` like

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.body', function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('body')) {
        return;
    }

    //your code
});
```

---

But in your case, since `.pdfcontent` is covering the entire `.body` you may want to

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.body .pdfcontent', function (e) {
    var body = $('.body');
    var width = body.width();
    var height = body[0].scrollHeight;

    var left = (e.pageX / width) * 100;
    var top = (e.pageY / height) * 100;
    setElement(left, top);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r3qx8udh/)

Comment: Thanks.. but now the event doesn't even works for `.body` element. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/70b4Loh1/13/)

Comment: nope.. can't do the updated approach because it is actually should be pdf document itself. But I think I should wrap another element to overcome this problem.. I will think on this workaround.. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr_Green the first approach will work, if you are actually clicking the `.body` element...

Comment: I can't see it as working. I am on chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/70b4Loh1/13/)

Comment: @Mr_Green http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/70b4Loh1/15/ - see the pdf content is covering the entire body

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. here the child element is just covering the parent element. [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/70b4Loh1/17/).

Comment: @Mr_Green there was a missing `$` in my code... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/70b4Loh1/18/

Comment: @Mr_Green another option is to target body or pdfcontent like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/70b4Loh1/19/

Comment: Thanks, I got that thought from your above post but I was trying `||` instead of what you did in the above comment :)

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/70b4Loh1/16/

I think you just need to bind to `.pdfcontent` instead of body

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.pdfcontent', function (e) {
```